# Cannot access IIS hosted page

Tags: windows, debugging, iis, robocopy

I am currently having issues with accessing a page, that I have robocopied from a server A to Server B. 
The paths and everything should be the same on server A and server B, as I robocopied the content of all the drives.

I've setup my page in IIS on server B, with the same configuration as server A. 
I've Tested that the default webpage works, which it does.

Why i try to access the page i've hosted on servre B, from server B, I get an error message stating the the "This page can’t be displayed"
Pinging the website => shows that it it try to access localhost = 127.0.0.1 - which is correnct.

Are their ways, beside the ones listed,  I can use to debug my sitatuation - and thereby find out what I am missing?

Comment: Check your iis access log. What's the substatus /win32 error code?  It's probably a file system permission issue? Goto explorer. Right click Properties on a problem file. Security tab. Advanced btn. Effective permissions. Enter the app pool identity (default app pool is named `iis apppool\defaultapppool` - change defaultapppool to your sites name). Click effective permissions. That lists what permissions the app pool has for that file.

Comment: IISreset, and remove webhistory  cookies and cache